# Forward ssh connections to docker container by hostname

Tags: ssh, reverse-proxy, docker

I have gotten into a very specific situation and although there are other ways to do this, I've kinda gotten obsessed with this and would like to find out a way to do it exactly like this:

#### Background

Say I have a server running several services tucked away in isolated docker containers. Since most of those services are http, I'm using an nginx proxy to expose specific subdomains to each service. For example, a node server is running on a docker container with its port `80` bound to `127.0.0.1:8000` on the host. I'll create a vhost in nginx that proxies all requests to `myapp.mydomain.com` to `http://127.0.0.1:8000`. That way, the docker container cannot be accessed from outside, except through `myapp.mydomain.com`.

Now I want to start a [gogs](https://gogs.io/) docker container in such a way that `gogs.mydomain.com` points to the gogs container. So I start [this gogs container](https://hub.docker.com/r/gogs/gogs/) with port `8000` bound to `127.0.0.1:8001` on the host. And an nginx site proxying requests to `gogs.mydomain.com` to `http://127.0.0.1:8001` and it works well...

However, gogs being a git container, I would also like to access the repos like through `git@gogs.mydomain.com:org/repo` but that doesn't work with the current setup. One way to make that work would be to bind the port `22` of the container to the port `0.0.0.0:8022` on the host, and then the git ssh url can be something like `git@gogs.mydomain.com:8022/repo`.

(That doesn't seem to work; when I push to an origin with uri like that, git demands the password for user `git` on `gogs.mydomain.com` - instead of `gogs.mydomain.com:8022` - but that's probably something I'm doing wrong and out of scope for this question, however, I would appreciate any diagnosis for that too)

#### Problem

My main concern is, that I want the ssh port `<gogs container>:22` to be proxied just like I am proxying http ports using nginx; i.e. any ssh connections to `gogs.mydomain.com` get passed on to the container's port `22`. Now I can't bind the container's ssh port to the host's ssh port because there is already an sshd running on the host. Also, that would mean that any connections to `*.mydomain.com` get passed to the container's sshd.

---

I want any ssh connections to:

- `mydomain.com` `host.mydomain.com` or mydomain's IP address to be accepted and forwarded to the sshd on the host
- `gogs.mydomain.com` or `git.mydomain.com` to be accepted an passed on to the sshd on the gogs container
- `*.mydomain.com` (where `*` is anything other than the possibilities above) to be rejected

If it were http, I could easily make that work through nginx. Is there a way to do that for ssh?

---

(Also would like to go out on a limb and ask: is there a way to accomplish that with *any* tcp service in general?)

Any insights into the way I'm trying to do it here, are also welcome. I don't mind being told when what I'm trying to do is utterly stupid.

---

#### What I've already got in my mind:

Maybe I could share the sshd socket on host with the container as a `ro` volume? That would mean the sshd inside the container could pick up all connections to `*.mydomain.com`. Could there be a way to make the sshd inside the container *reject* all connections other than `gogs.mydomain.com` or `git.mydomain.com`? However, the sshd on the host will pick up all the connections to `*.mydomain.com` anyway including `gogs.mydomain.com`; so there would be a conflict. I dunno, I haven't actually tried it. *Should* I try it?

Answer (score 3):

Doing this "by hostname" is simply not inside the scope of ssh. The ssh protocol itself does not support name-based virtual hosting (in fact HTTP is the exception from the rule here).

The SSHd on the receiving side can never know what hostname you asked your client to connect to as this information is not passed inside the protocol.

If you just need a few clients to work with this you can configure each client to connect to your server and then jump to the docker container like follows:

```
Host yourcontainer
        Hostname internal.ip.of.your.container
        ProxyCommand ssh your.docker.host nc %h %p
```

This way ssh will invoke the proxy command which will open an ssh session to your host and call `netcat` to establish a connection to your container. This way you don't really need to expose your containers ssh port to the outside world.

Answer (score 0):

Recent OpenSSH versions have the ProxyJump directive and -J flag:

```
ssh -J proxyuser@jumphost user@target
```